# Fixing enterprise lane when certs are expired

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

So 2 of Apples signing certs expired last week which messed up a lot of other companies certs down the line from them.

We use Fastlane to manage our builds and deployments. We got our production lane working again since, but I can't figure out how to get the enterprise lane back in operation.

We have our certificates repo on Github.
We have a production Apple developer account used for all production and TestFlight builds.
We also have an enterprise Apple developer account which we use for internal builds.

In the certificates repo on Github there are branch for all the builds including an enterprise branch with a cert, p12 and provisioning file. These seems to be static and have been there since they were created. (Were they created via Fastlane CLI then or were they created manually and somehow imported to the repo).

In the enterprise lane I can see we use the readonly flag set to true so we do not overwrite the files in the enterprise branch.

Given that the mobileprovisioning file has expired or is invalid what should I do to replace it correctly in the repo.

I tried going on the enterprise Apple Developer account and creating the mobile provisioning manually and I replaced the one that was on the repo. But that caused an error:

```
ERROR [2022-04-18 15:53:28.01]: wrong final block length
DEBUG [2022-04-18 15:53:28.01]: Error decrypting '/var/folders/bl/wbxjgtzx7j5_mjsmfr3ynlc00000gp/T/d20220418-4893-vw14o9/profiles/enterprise/InHouse_com.********.enterprise.********-ios.mobileprovision'
ERROR [2022-04-18 15:53:28.01]: Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!
```

What is the correct approach to use Fastlane to create and replace the .p12, cert and .mobilieprovision files in the repo? CLI commands or doing some kinda of import?

I would be really grateful for any suggestions.